# how to make a class that can be initialized using object or regular parameter constructor in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

so I want to make a class that can be initialized in two ways.

first, by using regular parameter, like this

```
class User {
    name: string
    age: number

    constructor(name: string, age: number) {
        this.name = name
        this.age = age
    }
}
```

or can be initialized by using an object like this

```
type CustomParameter = {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

class User {
    name: string
    age: number

    constructor(parameters: CustomParameter) {
        this.name = parameters.name
        this.age = parameters.age
    }
}
```

I don't want to make two different classes, I want to make a class with multiple constructors. so I try to use function overloading, so I thought I can do something like this, but it has errors

```
type CustomParameter = {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

class User {
    name: string
    age: number

    constructor(parameters?: CustomParameter, name: string, age: number)
    constructor(parameters: CustomParameter, name?: string, age?: number) {

       if (!parameters) {
           this.name = name
           this.age = age
       } else {
           this.name = parameters.name
           this.age = parameters.age
       }

    }
}
```

the code above is actually a simplified version, the class actually has a lot of properties. so it will be tedious if I do something like

```
const somebody = new Human(parameters.name, parameters.age) // <---- it is easy if only 2 params
// but it will be tedious if I have to initialize a class with more than 10 properties 
// over and over again
// so I think it will be easier if I just put the object in the class constructor
```

the error is like this

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use overloading something like this:

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/vW4GAm)

```ts
type CustomParameter = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

class User {
  name: string;
  age: number;

  constructor(name: string, age: number);
  constructor(parameters: CustomParameter);
  constructor(first: CustomParameter | string, age?: number) {
    if (typeof first === "string") {
      this.name = first;
      this.age = age!;
    } else {
      this.name = first.name;
      this.age = first.age;
    }
  }
}

new User("wewe", 12);
new User({ name: "wewe", age: 12 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go (for TS4.0+) is to give the constructor a rest parameter `...args` whose type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of [labeled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) [rest tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types).  Then you can check the `length` property of that rest parameter as the discriminant of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) to figure out which set of parameters was passed in:

```
class User {
    name: string
    age: number
    constructor(...args: [parameters: CustomParameter] | [name: string, age: number]) {
        if (args.length === 1) {
            const [parameters] = args;
            this.name = parameters.name
            this.age = parameters.age
        } else {
            const [name, age] = args;
            this.name = name
            this.age = age
        }
    }
}
```

That compiles just fine with no type assertions needed.  From the caller's side, it looks like an overloaded constructor with named parameters:

```
new User({ name: "Alice", age: 30 });
// 1/2, User(parameters: CustomParameter): User

new User("Bob", 35);
// 2/2, User(name: string, age: number): User
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYAUCGAnTqLATZQC8UA3gFBQ1QB2eEAXFEtgJZ0DmANNbZi7N6cVACMilAL6VKAYwA2mBAigBVBEQr8aDfCzacuOqIOF1RE7CbnI6bOHJTYAFADoPOLghYBtMDiMhNg+sIgoGIH4wQC6UAA+UL56wobcPKZCLBbiRDEAlNq0xVDsAGZQLl4IbgoQ3MAAFqQkZACMhVQl3VC29sBJAbjRRAhxZNUA3CY9UE3sNSmkUENBo24pMz3zNWbLqyMhbmZbNFJQEAqaRbO0fUhJKRlm46bY3tO3tDsbjMubXxoPz2EyEpygMmKMhklDoEAA7upNK5yPRGCwAEQAQQU7DkEAxzyyUAAzAAGCH5aYAempUDa1IATBkNEQXAcCKMWPAkGgsMNOdh8ixWdZYQikWyMQAhZBiQmkgCsVMotKgjKZLORLhSBmAHHSmXMliIwsl2CAA)